# Error while trying to build python application in openshift in requirements.txt

Tags: python, flask, openshift, minishift

I am not familiar with python web applications. I am trying build and deploy my application on Openshift container. But it is throwing errors because of requirements.txt.
Below are my logs.
Glad if someone can give some pointers!

I am basically trying to build an app to upload and process data files. 
App github link is: https://github.com/hanvitha92/UtilityToProcessData

requirements.txt :

```
gunicorn
Flask
flask_restful
xlrd
pandas
```

Error message:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 433, in get_provider module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq] KeyError: 'numpy' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 20, in <module> File "/tmp/pip-build-mvq1efv9/pandas/setup.py", line 732, in <module> ext_modules=maybe_cythonize(extensions, compiler_directives=directives), File "/tmp/pip-build-mvq1efv9/pandas/setup.py", line 475, in maybe_cythonize numpy_incl = pkg_resources.resource_filename('numpy', 'core/include') File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1160, in resource_filename return get_provider(package_or_requirement).get_resource_filename( File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 435, in get_provider
__import__(moduleOrReq) ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-mvq1efv9/pandas You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 19.0.2 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command. error: build error: non-zero (13) exit code from
172.30.1.1:5000/openshift/python@sha256:3dcb46be7bcc22a43f64ac078c8abe8e1ddafff729df39775052cbf1d0eef215
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with openshift, but this error is complaining that it can't find the `numpy` module. Do you need that in your `requirements.txt` or in some other build requirements?

Comment: No, I did not use it in my files. But I am guessing it is trying to run setup.py after requirements. I do not have much knowledge about it!

Comment: Did you then try adding it to ``requirements.txt``? Some Python packages don't seem to properly express dependencies on ``numpy`` and expect it to already be installed, so you have to list it (at start of file). Even then, depending on how ``pip`` orders things, it might try and install things in the wrong order such that it isn't installed first, so you might get the same error.

Comment: Also try forcing the use of latest ``pip``, by adding to your repo the file ``.s2i/environment``, with it containing ``UPGRADE_PIP_TO_LATEST=1``. The latest ``pip`` version may also handle it better.

Comment: UPGRADE_PIP_TO_LATEST=1 worked! thanks @GrahamDumpleton